# Retry Popup on Ok

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have not stated anywhere in my code nor JavaScript that the page should refresh upon clicking the OK button. But as the user clicks the OK button, the retry popup comes up. 
I am not sure what is the reasoning behind this.

Here is my code for the OK button:

```
protected void btn_ok_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tree_items.Nodes.Clear();           
    TableClass.MainTable = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection();
    connection1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["A"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("GetStuff", connection1);
    command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", solution_id));

    command1.CommandTimeout = 600;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);

    connection1.Open();
    adapter1.Fill(TableClass.MainTable);

    GenerateTreeView(TableClass.MainTable);    

    adapter1.Dispose();
    command1.Dispose();
    connection1.Dispose();
}
```

Here is the JavaScript for OK button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_ok" runat="server" Height="32px" OnClick="btn_ok_click"
    Text="OK" Width="100px" />
```

Please help.
Here is the GenerateTreeviw code:

```
private void GenerateTreeView(DataTable table)
        {
            DataRow[] foundRows = table.Select("ParentId = -1", "OrderIndex");
            TreeNode RootParentNode = null;

            int j = 1;
            foreach (DataRow i in foundRows)
            {
                string NewParentNodeName = i.Field<string>("Name");

                string NewParentNodeKey = Convert.ToString(i.Field<int>("ItemId"));
                RootParentNode = new TreeNode(NewParentNodeName, NewParentNodeKey);              
                i["OrderIndex"] = j;
                j++;


                GenerateChildNodes(table, NewParentNodeKey, RootParentNode);
                tree_items.Nodes.Add(RootParentNode);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code for the ok button is server-side code.  How is it going to run if the page doesn't post to the server?  What's causing the "retry" dialog (I'm assuming by that you mean the browser asking the user if they want to re-post the form data) seems external to the code you've shown us.  The code you show doesn't render the button or perform the original post, it just handles the button click on the server.  Can you reproduce the error with a fully-working minimal example?

Comment: what GenerateTreeView(TableClass.MainTable) do? would that rendering your webpage control that trigger the retry popup ?

Comment: It just adds the items in the treeview list from a database

Comment: Is there any way I can block it?

Comment: do you have the image to show what retry popup is ? since it is a web page you could use developer tool to see what causing that.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior in ASP.net is that when you click a button, the browser makes a new request to the server with information about the button being clicked. This is called a postback.

You did say that the page should reload when you said `runat="server"` on the button in the .aspx file.

I see two workarounds:

AJAX.

You can have ASP.net AJAX update only part of the page, or you can turn off `runat=server` have an AJAX call hit a webpage webmethod which does this

Change "Retry Popup"

Or you can change how the "retry" dialog comes up? Is that in your page load method? You could put that only `if (!this.IsPostBack)`

Comment: I think the main error is the difference between "postback" and "reload."  The "retry" dialog definitely shouldn't come up in regular use of postbacks.  It sounds like something else is wrong external to the code provided.

Comment: I can not produce the retry popup but when my computer is remotely used by others they can produce it.

Comment: @user1047883 Where is the code that does the retry popup, can we see that too?

Comment: There is no code for that. This is all there is for the Ok button. But When the user clicks ok it pops up that message

Comment: @David What do you mean something external is wrong? I mean when the user clicks ok it only goes through the code provided above. I am not sure what is causing the retry pop up

Comment: @user1047883 Can you provide more information on the retry popup? the number one hit for "retry popup" on google is this question, can you provide an image?